# Add a watch statement in Indium?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to add a watch statement in [Indium](https://github.com/NicolasPetton/Indium) like you can in the node [debugging utility](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html)?

from [Debugger | Node.js v9.10.1 Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_watchers):

> It is possible to watch expression and variable values while
>   debugging. On every breakpoint, each expression from the watchers list
>   will be evaluated in the current context and displayed immediately
>   before the breakpoint's source code listing.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method that I have found to be effective in lieu of a watch facility is adding a conditional breakpoint using `M-x indium-add-conditional-breakpoint` and using a `console.log(...)` expression.  Since that always returns undefined, it will print to the `*JS REPL*` buffer whenever passing that line of code.

The behavior is less than ideal since it is different than a watch statement (i.e. multiple watch statements are not printed simultaneously).